# How to list all files in folder?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, html

So I have this page I'm working on and I have a directory named 'products' in the same directory where index.html is. I'm trying to create a script that will count all the jpg files in the 'products' folder and then create an img element with each of those. any ideas of how i can do this?

Comment: On the server or the client?

Comment: You will probably need to use server side scripting to handle this.  Look into solutions like PHP, Ruby on Rails, Node.js, Flask (Python), and others to support this capability (most of those are frameworks which may be heavy for such a simple use case, but they're options if you're looking for more dynamic capabilities).  JS that's served to the client won't be able to list directories on the server (which is a good thing, because security!)

Comment: @mkaatman the client

Answer (score 0):

If you want do this on server side then use a PHP and create your own code like this one:

```
// allimg.php
<?php
$dir = "path/products/";
$imgs = glob($dir."*.jpg");
foreach($imgs as $image)
{
   echo '<img src="'.$image.'">'; // or <span>$image</span>
}
?>
```

And HTML index.html File to view it correctly.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Get All Images</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php include 'allimg.php'; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

All modern browsers'll refuse you attempting show a local folders, files because of protection rules.

Comment: this assumes server is running php ... those assumptions can't be made without input from OP .... could be running any number of other languages and not php

Comment: Yeah ... you're right. I just posted this to him just for a main source from which he could get an another answer.

Answer (score 0):

This can only be done in a server environment or using something that simulates a server environment on your local computer, like MAMP/WAMP or Node.  Javascript cannot access local folder contents in that manner.  It can get and insert local content like images, videos, or Javascript/CSS files, but that's about the limit of what it can do.

This is for security reasons.  Imagine opening someone else's Javascript file on your computer and it runs a script to erase all the files in your C drive.